# Rally App SDK 1.32: Chooser unable to access PortfolioItems with generic query after recent restructuring

Tags: javascript, rally

It seems that the Chooser in App SDK 1.32, though the query should be generic enough to pull the correct items, is not able to find any. Here is the code, which, even with the recent changes, I would think would be able to pull the data fine.

```
piChooser = new rally.sdk.ui.Chooser({
    type: 'PortfolioItem',
    title: 'Choose a Portfolio Item',
    fetch: 'FormattedID,Name',
    query: 'PortfolioItemType.Name = "MRU"',
    width: 500,
    height: 500
}, rallyDataSource);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this looks like a Defect, which interestingly does not appear related to the 9/1 code release, as I was able to reproduce this on a local instance of Rally running an earlier code base (2012.05.19). It looks like it is a general problem with rally.sdk.ui.Chooser for PortfolioItem artifacts - the Chooser fails to display them, even if you specify no query.

I've filed a Defect with Rally Development on this. You may wish to submit a Case to rallysupport@rallydev.com if you would like updates on the Defect.

Comment: Hm.., I am not sure if it is a defect. It worked perfectly fine before the PI structure changes. Well, other than only being able to display/filter [by] the Name field, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the update - I checked with the Rally development team and they confirmed that the recent changes of the 9/1/2012 code release probably did impact the Chooser component in AppSDK 1.xx.